# MYSQL - Use longblob with 4GB despite max_allowed_packet of 1GB

Tags: mysql

Recently I was given an old application using MySQL 5.6 which has a problem with big files.

I found many threads stating that max_allowed_packet cannot be set to more than 1GB as this is the defined limit for MySQL. However there is this datatype LONGBLOB which is defined as supporting sizes up to 4GB.

As I can't imagine, that they defined a datatype, that you can't use - how is it possible to save Blobs this size despite max_allowed_packet being 1GB?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to split the blob being uploaded into chunks which are equal or smaller to the `max_allowed_packet` size. They are uploaded via multiple calls to the MySQL C API function [`mysql_stmt_send_long_data()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-stmt-send-long-data.html) (q.v.). The MySQL command line client should handle this for you. In your own code you may have to check whether your preferred language's API handles this or whether you have to do so yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped of an easier approach, but I guess that doesn't exist. As the application is written in Java, I told the devs, that they should look for something alike the function you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of *practical* reasons for not trying to use a full 4GB.

- It would take a long time to perform the query.* Slow
- What if tomorrow's blob is 5GB long?
- It clogs up replication.
- For things like images/videos, it is likely to be better to put the blob in a file, then let html handle it via `<img...>` (etc).
- Cluttering RAM (that might be better used for caching, etc)

Anyway, you are losing only the range between 1G and 4G.  16M..1G works; so does less than 16M (as well as `MEDIUMBLOB`, etc).

Comment: I'm with you, but still - why create a datatype that is nearly impossible to use. It gives people false hope and/or leads them in the wrong direction.
The mentioned application uses longblob and obviously the original devs had files up to 4GB in mind. Now I'm stuck with their application and have to find a way to handle this.

Comment: @Picl - I can _guess_ that 25 years ago, it "seemed like a good idea".  Then the implementation of things somewhat ignored the issue.  Remember, very few computers had even 2GB of RAM back then.  I do give them praise for having very few "hard" limits.